# Non-negative solution to matrix equation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrices

I want to solve $Ax = b$ subject to the constraint that all of the elements of $x$ are non-negative.  If such a solution does not exist, I want to find non-negative $x$ such that the quadratic form $(Ax - b)^T (Ax-b)$ is minimized.  What kind of algorithm will let me do this?

Comment: what are dimensions of matrix $A$? Is it square, more columns than rows or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put differently, you want to solve the following optimization problem
$$
\min_x \|Ax-b\|^2\ \text{s. t.}\ x\geq 0.
$$
This is a quadratic and convexly constrained minimization problem which can be solved in many ways. There are several software packages around to do the task, for example the [quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/quadprog.html) routine of the Matlab Optimization toolbox should work here. However, the choice should at least depend on the size and the type of the matrix.